# JWT auth production enpoints UNSPECIFIED_ERROR String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

Recently integrated JWT based auth for DocuSign integration, in the development environment pointing to demo DocuSign, there are no issues. However in production environment we are facing below issue while retrieving login_information by passing oAuthToken

```
400 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "String cannot be of zero length.\r\nParameter name: oldValue"
}
```

As per wiki, I am using below url to generate tokens

> For the developer demo environment, the base URI is https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth
> For the production platform, the base URI is https://account.docusign.com/oauth/auth

If token contains dot (.) I am able to reproduce the issue against production endpoints.

```
curl -H "Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAA" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "String cannot be of zero length.\r\nParameter name: oldValue"
}
```

with the same auth token against demo endpoint, above error is not reproducible.

```
curl -H "Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAA" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information
{
  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. The `login_information` API method is **not supported** when OAuth v2.0 access tokens are used. It sometimes works (eg your experience in demo), but in general does not work and leads to errors.

   Instead, use the [/oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API call to obtain the user's name, email, account_id, and base URL. Note that the URL (for development) is https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo. Not demo.docusign.net.
2. It is not clear if the access token you're receiving back from the JWT flow is good or not. Best way to find out is to use it with /oauth/userinfo. If there is some issue, then we'll work on that.

### Also, use API version v2.1

[API v2 is entering maintenance mode](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/esignature-rest-api-v20-entering-maintenance-mode) and should not be used for new applications.